# Lazy UILabel property of custom control

Tags: ios, swift, custom-controls, lazy-initialization

I want to be able to set the title of my custom control in interface builder and implement the title as a UILabel.  I have created my properties thus:

```
@IBInspectable var titleText: String? {
    get {
        return title.text
    }
    set(newTitleText) {
        title.text = newTitleText
    }
}
@IBInspectable lazy var title: UILabel = UILabel.init()
```

Is this a good/recommended way to do this?  I also want the control to layout the UILabel if the title text has been set and plan to do this by overriding `layoutSubviews` - again is this recommended or would you suggest a different pattern?

My ultimate aim is to be able to enable a designer to configure my control from IB and exposing the UILabel as a property that can be configured in IB would be my ideal.

Comment: Why do you think declaring `title` lazily helps? I can't see any reason why you would declare a `UILabel` optional. Moreover, don't call the initializer directly using `init()`, use the shorthand notation, `UILabel()`.

Comment: Thanks David.  As you can see I am new to Swift (please go easy).  The reason I was initialising lazily is there many times where the user (or designer) won't set a title, so only want to create one if there is actually some title text to display.  Equally want to ignore the layout of the title if the UILabel is nil.

Answer (score 1):

`@IBInspectable` can be used only with the following types:

```
Int
CGFloat
Double
String
Bool
CGPoint
CGSize
CGRect
UIColor
UIImage
```

So, no, you can not "expose a `UILabel`" for design-time manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think that you need to make your variable `lazy` here, also, if you want to create a new instance of UILabel, it's better to user the constructor `UILabel()`.

Now, I am not sure if I understand correctly your question, but if I did, then you **can** expose your custom view properties (a string that represents your title label for example) to the Attributes Inspector.

You would do it like so:

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    @IBInspectable var title: String? {
        didSet { self.titleLabel.text = title }
    }

}
```

To break up the code above :

First you make the class (your custom view) `@IBDesignable` so that it supports live preview in the Interface Builder.
Then, inside your custom view class, you create a title property (which is a `String`) and make sure to make it `@IBInspectable` so that you can change this property later via the Attributes Inspector.
Finally you add a property observer ( `didSet` ) so that the text property of your custom label is updated whenever you change the title property from the Attributes Inspector.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I have IBDesignable for the class and IBInspectable for the String property.  I would like the control to be entirely self contained if possible, so no outlets to subviews added in IB, but allow as much customisation in code or IB as possible.  Does that make sense?  It is for a graph component, so the title is the most obvious example.  The graph may or may not have a title, and from what I've read it is best practice to expose a label so that the customisation is consistent with the rest of the OS. I come from an ObjC background, so this is all a bit new.  Cheers Dave.